# iPhone Activation lock with an unknown Apple ID

Tags: iphone, icloud, email

I broke my iPhone 4s while I was travelling. So, I put it in my locker. I repaired it yesterday and connected it to iTunes. Unfortunately, My iPhone activated **Activation Lock**. Only one way to enter my Apple ID is to reset my password but, there is email that i don't know. It looks like `g*****@m*****.com`. `g*****` should be my email and I don't remember signing up with this kind of email.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Were you signed into this iPhone previously with your Apple ID/iCloud ID?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to Apple as they can bypass the iCloud lock with proof that you are the owner of the said iPhone.

Comment: how can i do that can u explain me more

Comment: If you bought the iPhone brandnew, you can go to an Apple store with the proof (like the bill) taht you are the owner so that they can unlock it for you. But if you buy this iPhone from someone else, then the email locking the iCloud account is that someone email. Try contact that person.